# Installing Flash during system installation

Tags: installation, flash, ubiquity

Why is it we don't give the user the option to install the Flash plugin during installation when we do install the Fluendo MP3 codec? Flash is just as essential to an average user's browsing experience as MP3 playback is to their audio experience. Are the nature of the restrictions different, or is this just an oversight?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't install Flash also? I just tried it in a 11.04 VM and it mentions Flash explicitly with the same checkbox as mp3. Maybe they added that as a clarification?

Comment: It already is. Today I installed Natty x64 and Flash worked fine (Opera, FF, Chromium).

Comment: You're both right. I just tested it in a VM and it works out of the box. I'll post an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the option to pre-install Flash does exists in the Ubuntu installer. The following dialogue will be presented to the user during installation, and checking the second option will install it for you.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Because flash is closed source,but free and Adobe has very specific rules in their [EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/flashplayer_10_1_eula.html) that control who(Themselves) can distribute it and who can't (everyone else).